# ProgressDialog в отдельном потоке

Tags: android, java

Использую AsyncTask для выполнения тяжелого кода, но нужно приостановить главный поток пока выполняется AsyncTask.

Можно ли сделать **ProgressDialog в отдельном потоке**, когда **главный поток приостановлен**?

Answer (score 2):

А почему нельзя создавать ProgressDialog в ui-потоке (onPreExecute()), показывать его, и делать dismiss по завершении AsyncTask (в onPostExecute()) ?

Comment: Потому что я вызываю через new MyTask.execute(...).get(); который приостанавливает главный поток и ждет когда асинхр задача выполнится. И в MyTask идет проверка если тяжелый код выполнился успешно, то выполняет дальше код в главном потоке.

Comment: >Потому что я вызываю через new MyTask.execute(...).get();

не вызывайте так.

Comment: В главном потоке стоит проверка и тогда код не будет выполняться потому что другой поток не успеет передать значение для проверки в ui

Comment: если главный поток(UI) приходится останавливаться - то вы выбрали неверный путь

Comment: в чём проблема сделать метод, в который вынести тот самый код, который надо "исполнять дальше" и вызывать этот метод в onPostExecute() ?

Comment: @geek я конечно попробую так, но я не представляю как можно передать переменные разного типа в MyTask. Кусок кода: http://goo.gl/4z9G5i
ObjectItem это тип переменных для моего Adapter

@Andreich ну так подскажи как мне сделать?

Comment: Если нужно много переменных в AsyncTask передавать - то да, лучше передавать их кучей в объекте

судя по скриншоту - я не вижу, почему бы всю работу с json и загадочным объектом wf не вынести в какой-то класс, который уже передавать в AsyncTask

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, решил задачу передачей ArrayList в AsyncTask